# CSS image background not showing on some pages for mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I am very confused. On mobile, I have a home page with a Halloween background image, but then when I go to my other page that is being affected with the same CSS does not show the background image. It is working because it does the highlight on the text but once again no background image? Below will be my CSS and images of what is happening. Also it works fine on desktop!

Image one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FBgo.jpg

Image two: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjnmZ.png

(Here is the halloween image I am using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1ee2.jpg)

CSS:

```css
:root {
  --clr-he-hl: rgb(255, 119, 0);
  --clr-dark: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  --clr-light: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  --img-bg-he: url(../holiday-img/101.jpg);
}

/* Start Halloween CSS */

body {
  background-image: var(--img-bg-he);
}

p {
  background-color: var(--clr-he-hl);
}

h1 {
  background-color: var(--clr-he-hl);
}

h2 {
  background-color: var(--clr-he-hl);
}

h3 {
  background-color: var(--clr-he-hl);
}

h4 {
  background-color: var(--clr-he-hl);
}

.mobile-lable {
  background-color: var(--clr-he-hl);
}

.gray {
  background-image: var(--img-bg-he);
}

.gray_XL {
  background-image: var(--img-bg-he);
}

a.nav-menu-link {
  color: var(--clr-light);
  background-color: var(--clr-he-hl);
}

a.nav-menu-link:hover {
  color: var(--clr-light);
}

#yt-img {
  background-color: var(--clr-he-hl);
}

li {
  background-color: var(--clr-he-hl);
}

/* End Halloween CSS */
```

Comment: First of all run a html check and fix html errors. You have some invalid markup on the page. The pic issue might be browser based (on SAFARI Iphone 6) it did not work, on chrome however it workes quite well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, Bartek. It is not working on any browser on my iPhone 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I did not clear cookies correctly on my browser. I am very late to respond, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Probably background image is overridden.
Either make:

```
body {
  background-image: var(--img-bg-he) !important;
}
```

OR

```
body, .gray, .gray_XL {
  background-image: var(--img-bg-he) !important;
}
```

(Please note: I can't make comments because reputation lower than 50)

Do share full code if it doesn't solve issue.
I can try helping further.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I had to do this else were in my CSS, so thanks!